# Timeout trying to lock table; why is this occurring and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, database, jpa, playframework

I've been using JPA in the Play Framework for some time now, and everything was going fine - however, I have now come up against an error which I'm not seeing any obvious solutions to. Just for some context, what I am trying to create is a basic social network.

I have a Post class:

```
public class Post extends Model {
private String owner;

private long timestamp;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> viewers;

private String content;

public Post(String owner, List<String> viewers, String content) {
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.owner = owner;
        this.viewers = viewers;
        this.content = content;
        System.out.println("Saving post by " + owner + " with timestamp:" + this.timestamp);
    }
(Getters and setters ignored here)
}
```

I have a User class which adds posts:

```
    public long addPost(String viewers, String content) {
        LinkedList<String> viewersList = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(viewers.split(",")));
        Post newPost = new Post(this.name, viewersList, content);
        newPost.save();
        return newPost.getTimestamp();
}
```

And I have a StreamManager handling notification of posts and retrieval of posts.

```
    public static void executePost(String content, String viewers) {
        System.out.println("Post content: " + content);
        String user = session.get("username");
        User u = User.connect(user);
        if (u == null) {
            System.out.println("User is null");
        }

        /* Add post to local record of posts */
        long timestamp = u.addPost(viewers, content);

        /* Send notification of post to server */
    }
```

I'm running my application with a thread pool of 3 threads, which means that there is some amount of concurrency in the system. While the system is waiting for a response from the server after notification (end of executePost), another thread is trying to access the newly created Post using this code:

```
    public static void retrievePost(String owner, String timestamp) {
        byte[] postAndKey = new byte[1024];
        byte[] post = null;
        byte[] encryptedKey = null;
        User u = User.connect(owner);
        Post.findAll();
        //List<Post> posts = (Post.find("byOwner", owner).fetch());
        System.out.println("Looking for post by " + owner + " at timestamp: " + timestamp);

        //System.out.println("Looking through: " + posts.size() + " posts");
```

At `Post.findAll()` the framework throws a nasty error, telling me that there is a `Timeout trying to lock table "POST"`. I suspect that this is because one thread is still in `executePost()` while another is trying to access the post in `retrievePost()`. Considering that the Post has been 'saved', however, shouldn't the lock have been released? Is this really the reason, and is there any way around the error?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about Play and JPA but the first step is to put some logging statements around `executePost`, `newPost.save();` and `Post.findAll();` to confirm your hypothesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference, if anyone else is having a similar issue: I fixed it by explicitly sleeping the calling thread using `await()`, which meant that it gave up all its locks, allowing the thread in `retrievePost()` acess to the table.